# Discord,js Mongoose connection failed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot for discord in **discord.js** and i cannot connect it to the Mongoose database | *mongoose ver: 5.11.14* and *discord.js ver 12.5.3*

Error log:

```
The Bot has disconnected from the DB.
C:\Users\utilizator\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:299
          callback(new MongoError(document));
                   ^

MongoError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\utilizator\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:299:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\utilizator\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\utilizator\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
}
```

The code i used for mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports  = {
    init: () => {
        const dbOptions = {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            autoIndex: false,
            poolSize: 5,
            connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
            family: 4
        };
        mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://denox:${process.env.PASS}@currencybotdb.tyfsmsg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, dbOptions);
        mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

        mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
            console.log('The Bot has connected to the DB.');
        });
        mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
            console.log('The Bot has disconnected from the DB.');
        });
        mongoose.connection.on('err', (err) => {
            console.log('Error connecting to the DB:' + err);
        });
    }
}
```

I have no idea how i can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://denox:${process.env.PASS}@currencybotdb.tyfsmsg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, dbOptions);
```

to:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.PASS)
```

and in your .env file:

```
PASS=mongodb+srv://denox:YOURPASSWORD@currencybotdb.tyfsmsg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```